# What was the ancestor of VAT called?

Tags: taxes

If I recall correctly, back in the Dutch golden age, a law was pressed on merchants forcing them to add an extra coin to their prices which they would have to later pay to the government.

I believe this law was called something along the lines of "The 11th coin", yet I can't seem to recall its exact name.

What was this law called?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wikipedia to the rescue (At least possibly)

> The types of tax that were next in importance were the real and personal property taxes like the verponding, a kind of rates. This amounted to 8.5 percent (the Twelfth Penny) of the rental value of all real property. *[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Financial_history_of_the_Dutch_Republic#Taxation)*

Having said that, google produces multiple entries for the term "twelfth penny" tax - most of them have to do with France, and the few that have to do with the Netherlands are quotes from the works of Thomas Carlyle which are not relevant.

If I'm correct, the law was the verpondering.

Comment: It being a France law is very well possible. While once being a big interest to me, the exact details (or even big ones such as which country it took place in) have become a tad bit foggy. Thank you!

Comment: Another precedent was the Castillian [Alcabala](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alcabala), which the Duke of Alba tried to introduce into the Netherlands (they did not like that much).

Comment: Excellent find - Alcabala should be an answer to the question.